# fullPage.js - can't view content higher than section

Tags: html, fullpage.js

I have page based on fullPage.js and Bootsrap. By default is content in section vertically centered. But my content is dynamic and changes on click. It means, that my content has on every click different height and it cause div jumping on page.

Disabling vertical center solve the problem, but only for desktop. On smaller screen (mobiles, tablets) I can't see whole content in section.

With vertical center enabled the section is high as content.

Live example is more than word so:

1. Example with verticalCenter enabled (not working)
2. Example with verticalCenter disabled (not working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the solution was specify container height.

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to use the `responsiveWidth` or `responsiveHeight` options provided in fullpage.js. That's going to create the best user experience for small screen devices.

But if you still want autoScrolling then you can always go for the `scrollOverflow` option as [in this example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html) and to adjust the scroll bar dynamically you would have to call `$.fn.fullpage.reBuild()` on any click that changes triggers a change in the section's height.